# Are shebang invocations detectable?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, shebang

Is there a way for a bash script to detect if it's being run via the `#!/usr/bin/env` shebang?
Some magic bash foo that would let me write:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
if [ __INVOKED_VIA_USR_BIN_ENV__ ]; then 
  ...
```

Comment: Do you have access to the places where `env` is called? According to the man page the tool allows you to set environment variables in the call.

Comment: No, not in this case. Unfortunately I cannot tinker with `env` as it is used in shebangs I do not control. Messing with the shebang would be reverted whenever the script updates itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [last thing](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/env.c;h=6a5c246a571b08ce2796e52e22b0b00ca14e96cf;hb=HEAD#l156) that **env** (from coreutils) does is

```
execvp (argv[optind], &argv[optind]);
```

This means that **env** gets replaced with the other program, so you can't detect who started it. You can find out more in the [execvp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) man page.

Comment: Thanks for the links, Cristian. Seems like this is the final answer.